# ADX Command activity timing out after 1 hour despite specifying 2 hours of timeout

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am using ADX Command activity in ADFv2 (Azure Data Factory) to append data to one of the Kusto tables. But very frequently this fails throwing an error after an hour. If the underlying activity finishes within an hour, it succeeds but if it tries to run beyond 1 hour, it is terminated (times out).

When I check the operation status through Kusto Explorer on the basis of operations id that I get in the ADF error, I see that after 59 mins, the operation has failed

```
"The admin command execution timed out at..."
```

This is happening despite specifying 2 hours timeout for the ADX Command activity in the data factory. Why is that then timing out only after an hour? How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

ADX command activity limits the execution time by the specified Command timeout parameter where the limit is 1 hour. Please see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-factory-command-activity#create-an-azure-data-explorer-command-activity-within-the-foreach-activity)
[ADX Command activity - Command timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4VZ.jpg)

Comment: yes I see it now -- strange that there is also a timeout in 'General' tab of the activity and the one you cited exists in the 'Command' tab which is what has the limit of 1 hour , that is why it led to my confusion. But then our command does indeed take more than 1 hour in many cases. How to work around this 1 hour limitation ? Otherwise it's a dead end for us.

Comment: The timeout in the 'General' tab is the activity timeout, the Command timeout is the timeout for the request to ADX. Do you use async command? (.set-or-append async ..)

Comment: Yes the command that's sent to the activity is '.append async' , but still this is happening

Comment: In this case you'll need to partition the data and use a Foreach activity to run the command for the different partitions in parallel. If the query doesn't require serialization you can also use the distributed property, please see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query).

Comment: I see -- yea but there is just no way we can communicate to ADX to not cut off a 1 hour? Many other big data platforms like HDInsight don't have such limitation and we could easily have queries running for 3-4 hours also.